# A good way to share objects between C# and R subprocess?

Tags: c#, r

My goal is to run an R script as a subprocess from C# and then work with the result computed by the script.

Current solution is that the R script prints the result as json and then C# reads the standard output and parses the result. This is obviously very error-prone and hard to test and maintain.

What would be a better way to do this?
For example, is Apache Arrow suitable for this task? Or something like SWIG?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40659843/16730940 addresses a similar question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read R-script results from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381659/how-to-read-r-script-results-from-c-sharp)